# String replace Wordpress Site Title

Tags: php, title, customization

I want to get rid of a dash '-' in my Wordpress site title on mobile. To do that, I want to place a span around the dash, something like the below.

**Desired Result**

```
<h1 class="site-title">My Site Title <span class="remove-mob">-</span> Is Great</h1>
```

Here's my current PHP code, can anyone suggest an edit, so that I can add the span above around the dash contained within the site title?

**Current Code**

```
<h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**

You can do this using JavaScript.

First, add an id for your `h1` tag. I will use `mobId` here so your header tag will look like this:

```
<h1 class="site-title" id="mobId">My Site Title - Is Great</h1>
```

Then replace the hyphen with your desired code:

```
<script>
    var myStr = document.getElementById("mobId").innerHTML;
    var newStr = myStr.replace("-", "<span class='remove-mob'>-</span>");
    document.getElementById("mobId").innerHTML = newStr;
</script>
```

It can be written shorter, but i wrote the full code so you know what's going on.

**Method 2**

Strip using php `str_replace()`:

```
<h1 class="site-title">
        <?php echo str_replace("-","<span class='remove-mob'>-</span>", get_bloginfo('name')); ?>
</h1>
```

You can save `get_bloginfo();` in a variable and use that in the function instead, in case it happens to return an error because of quotes.

Comment: Thank you Jack, can this be done via PHP? I was thinking there might be away to search 'bloginfo' and strip out the dash.

Comment: Hi, i updated the code for you. I didn't put it in `functions.php` since we don't want to change `bloginfo()` across the whole website.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do this using a filter. The [**bloginfo()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/) function actually calls the [**get_bloginfo()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) function and echoing the result.

The [**get_bloginfo()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) has a filter bloginfo applied in the output before it's returned. So you can use add_filter to alter the result of the function.

Using this method, you won't have to edit your theme files.

UPDATE: I've edited the function to make sure it only runs once in the global variable, this should solve the issue of it editing other instances of **bloginfo** assuming the call in the header is the earliest.

```
function wpse253508_change_title( $output, $show ) {

    static $run_once;

    if ( "name" == $show && "change_title" != $run_once ) {
        $run_once = "change_title";
        $output = str_replace("-", "<span class='remove-mob'>-</span>", $output);

        return $output;
    }
    return $output;
}

add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'wpse253508_change_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You are right. But this will change the string across the entire website, including those in meta tags, footer, etc.

Comment: I've updated the code so it only runs once assuming the earliest call is in the header